# Fluent Assertion - compare models properties ignoring null values

Tags: c#, assert, fluent-assertions

case I am working on is - what is best solution to compare two objects with properties but excluding members with null values.

Ex.

```
objectA.prop1 = "value1";
objectA.prop2 = "value2";
objectA.prop3 = "value3";

expectedObjectB.prop1 = null;
expectedObjectB.prop2 = "value2";
expectedObjectB.prop3 = null;

objectA.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedObjectB);
```

It compares all properties one-to-one. How to make it compare only *prop2* in that case and ignore other?
Should I use Exclude method?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is use an anonymous object.
`BeEquivalentTo` looks at the expectation to decide what properties to consider when doing an structural equivalency comparison.

In this

```cs
class MyClass
{
    string Prop1 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

var subject = new MyClass
{
    Prop1 = "IrrelevantValue",
    Prop2 = "value2"
}


var expected = new
{
    Prop2 = "value2"
}

objectA.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

Comment: But property with null value can be different, sometimes it is prop1, sometimes prop2, even sometimes both of them

Comment: That sounds like a very fuzzy assertion to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it with custom IEquivalencyStep.

```
public class NullValueExcludingComparer : IEquivalencyStep
    {
        public bool CanHandle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config)
        {
            return context.Expectation is null;
        }

        public bool Handle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator parent, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And executing:

```
objectA.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedObjectB, options =>
    options.Using(new NullValueExcludingComparer())
);
```